# Convergence of integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\tan(x)\, dx$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

### Problem

Is following integral convergent ?

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\tan(x)\,dx $$

### Attempt to solve

We can solve first indefinite integral of $\tan(x)$
$$\int \tan(x)\,dx=-\ln(\cos(x))$$
Now we can calculate from 0 to $\pi/2$
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\tan(x)\,dx=-\ln(\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}))-(-\ln(\cos(0))$$
$$\approx 3.044343016\cdot 10^{-4}$$

I can get a tiny number for area from 0 to $\pi/2$. Now if you take a look at graph of $\tan(x)$ from 0 to $\pi/2$ you can see that when $x \rightarrow \pi/2$ y goes to $+\infty$ ? Now i doubt that my calculated value for the area is correct since area should be infinity too ? since area increases when y increases.

Comment: the thing is $\ln(\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}))$ is not defined. It tends to $-\infty$. So your calculations are write up to the last part. I don't know how you got the last part.))

Comment: Did you put in $(\pi/2)°$ instead of $(\pi/2)$ into cosine? Blindly entered into calculator, which is accidentally set to degrees? That shows the danger of using a calculator for values where you know the answer analytically.

Comment: @orion i can confirm this is the reason why the last part is incorrect.

Comment: @orion, when I use degrees instead of radians, I get $-\ln(\cos((\pi/2)^\circ))=0.00037585376$, not $0.0003044343016$.

Comment: Oh gosh, I think I figured it out:  The OP's calculator is using **gradians** (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradian).  A right angle, $\pi/2$ radians, is $100$ gradians, and $-\ln(\cos((\pi/2) grad))=-\ln(\cos(\pi^2/400))=0.0003044343$.

Comment: @BarryCipra i can also confirm this that unit that my calculator was set was gradians indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\tan(x)$ behaves as $1/x$ around the pole (technically, $1/(\pi/2-x)$, but the important thing is the asymptotic power law behaviour and you can always change variables). By knowing that integral of $1/x$ diverges, the integral of $\tan x$ will diverge too.

I don't know how you got your last number, but $\log \cos\frac{\pi}{2}=\log 0$ evidently diverges.

Answer (score 0):

I would even say that the problem you want to solve does not exist, as $\tan x$ is not defined for $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.